# python atexit error : the first argument must be callable

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.6, atexit

Using Python 3.6, I am trying to customize my error when a program terminates but getting a "TypeError:  the first argument must be callable". I have seen similar questions but they are relevant to scheduling which I am not trying. That's why I am raising it here.
The code I am trying:

```
import atexit
def greet_me(*arg, **kwargs):
    new_json = {}
    new_json['person'] = kwargs
    print('new_json = ', new_json)
    print('passed **kwargs = ', kwargs)
    print("*arg = ", arg)
    print('arg[0] = ', arg[0])
    if kwargs is not None:
       for key, value in kwargs.items():
           print ("%s == %s" %(key,value))

def do_some_tasks():
    print("some tasks are done")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    do_some_tasks()
    text1 = 'hello1'
    atexit.register(greet_me(text1, name='peter', age= 32, gender = 'male'))
```

The above code produces following:

```
some tasks are done
new_json =  {'person': {'name': 'peter', 'age': 32, 'gender': 'male'}}
passed **kwargs =  {'name': 'peter', 'age': 32, 'gender': 'male'}
*arg =  ('hello1',)
arg[0] =  hello1
name == peter
age == 32
gender == male
TypeError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-f01f4a5e6c64> in <module>()
       3     do_some_tasks()
       4     text1 = 'hello1'
 ----> 5     atexit.register(greet_me(text1, name='peter', age= 32, gender = 'male'))
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

In Python2.7, the errors appear slightly different:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py", line 24, in _run_exitfuncs
func(*targs, **kargs)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Any idea how to avoid such error?

Answer (score 2):

Don't *call*, `greet_me`, pass the function, and arguments.

Currently you `register` the return value, not the function, which python 2.7 recognizes as None, and which according to python 3 is not callable.

You could change line 5 (from traceback) to

```
atexit.register(greet_me, text1, name='peter', age= 32, gender = 'male')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please give me an example how to use it in my case?